# gdb does not run on Mojave 10.14.2

Tags: macos, gdb, macos-mojave

I have installed gdb on Mojave 10.14.2 following the description given in here:

https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/PermissionsDarwin

When I try to run the executable, it complains:

```
Starting program: /Users/sfv/test/code1 
[New Thread 0x1a03 of process 4658]
During startup program terminated with signal ?, Unknown signal.
```